# Is it possible to export Datadog Aurora dashboard as cloud formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, dashboard, datadog

I'm using [this built-in dashboard](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-aurora-using-datadog/) for monitoring Aurora and was wondering how can I have as code, as cloud formation stack precisely.

I'm aware of those three repos which do backup and monitoring of changing of the dashboard in the API and then commit back to GitHub, but I only want to export it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do that by using this api call: https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=python#get-a-screenboard
and then get it as a son file, which can be passed to cloud formation later.